# How can I get a link to load with overflow hidden and show full content on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a link to load with the text cut off at a certain width. Then when the user hovers over, it shows the full content of the anchor tag.  I have a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/GCXsq/564/ but it initially shows the full content of the link, and it also makes the link width 0 on hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/GCXsq/565/

Your main problem was that your hovering element had no (elemental) children, so you were always animating from 0 width.

Comment: I think I was staring at it for too long. Thank you!!

Comment: How can I change this so that the anchor doesn't need to be the child?

Comment: `<a class="expand"><span>Span is the child</span></a>`